# Can't access a specific Struct in an array on swift. Keep getting this error "Cannot call value of non-function type '""

Tags: arrays, swift, struct

I am trying to read and/or console print on of the elements of my array which consist of 28 structs. I can not access any of the struct on my array is says that "Cannot call value of non-function type '[Ficha]'" and I can't find why.. Sorry kind of a newbie on swift.. The section commented is where I discovered the problem but I can't even print one of the elements.

Please help

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

struct Ficha {
    var numero: Int
    var ladoA = 0
    var ladoB = 0
}

extension Ficha: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String {
        return "f\(numero) \(ladoA)/\(ladoB)"
    }
}

var dSet = [Ficha] ()
var rSet = [Int: Ficha] ()


func setDset () {
    dSet = []
    rSet = [:]
    var fj = 0
    var x1: Double = 0
    var ficha1 : Ficha


    var fichanum = 0
    for x in 0...6 {
        for y in x...6 {
            fichanum = fichanum + 1
            dSet.append(Ficha.init(numero: fichanum, ladoA: x, ladoB: y))
        }
    }
    dSet.shuffle()
}

setDset()    
print (dSet(2))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dSet` with parenthesis is incorrect, that's the syntax for a function. So the line:

```
print(dSet(2))
```

is assuming there's a function that returns something:

```
func dSet(_ x: Int) -> Something {
  return Something
}
```

To access an item at an index you use the square brackets, so it should be:

```
print(dSet[2])
```

Which will print the item at index 2 in the array `dSet`.

Comment: the short answer  is  you are using the () instead of using []

Comment: Thanks.  For your help

Comment: @gariva if this worked for you please mark the answer as correct

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, you access members of a collection using subscripts, which are invoked via `[]`, not `()` (which is for regular function calls).

You can simplify this code quite a bit, btw:

```
import UIKit

struct Ficha {
    var numero: Int
    var ladoA = 0
    var ladoB = 0
}

extension Ficha: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String {
        return "f\(numero) \(ladoA)/\(ladoB)"
    }
}

func calculateDset() -> [Ficha] {   
    let xyPairs = (0...6).flatMap { x in
        (x...6).map { y in (x: x, y: y) }
    }

    return zip(1..., xyPairs)
        .map { (fichanum, pair) in
            return Ficha(numero: fichanum, ladoA: pair.x, ladoB: pair.y)
        }
        .shuffled()
}

let dSet = calculateDset()
print(dSet[2])
```

1. UIKit already imports Foundation
2. Make functions return values, don't set them directly.
3. Don't set initial values to variables, only to immediate overwrite them with something else.
4. rSet, fj, x1, and ficha1 are unused, delete them.